# Mean and variance of geometric distribution, probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> $2.$ Compute the mean and variance of the geometric distribution.
>
> Hints: It is sometimes easier to compute $\text{E}[X(X-1)]$ than
>   $\text{E}[X^2]$. Note that
>   $\text{E}[X(X-1)]=\text{E}[X^2]-\text{E}[X]$. The geometric series
>   formula is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}$$ If you
>   differentiate this once and then again you get the useful identities:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty
> > nr^{n-1}=\frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{1-r},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\sum_{n=2}^\infty
> > n(n-1)r^{n-2}=\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\frac{1}{1-r}$$ The following is not to
>   be turned in. This same "summation by differentiating" trick can be
>   used in other setting. Take the binomial identity
>   $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$$ Differentiate with
>   respect to $x$, then set $x=p$, $y=1-p$ and you get an identity that
>   helps you compute the mean of the binomial distribution. Differentiate
>   twice and you get an identity that will lead to the variance.

I am not sure where I am going wrong in trying to reach the proper solution.
Can anyone help me to solve this, please?

Comment: The question is not clear. Where did you stuck?